# array_intersect for sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I've an associative array like this.

```
$lang['lbl_mylabel1'] = array('key1' => 'value1');
$lang['lbl_mylabel2'] = array('key2' => 'value1');
$lang['lbl_mylabel3'] = array('key3' => 'value1');
$lang['lbl_mylabel4'] = array('key4' => 'value2');
$lang['lbl_mylabel5'] = array('key5' => 'value3');
```

And I have a variable named `value1` through which I want to compare values of the sub-array and return all those elements whose values are `value1`.

So how can I use `array_intersect` or any possible efficient method to return me the elements of `$lang array` with values1.

The answer of above code should be the first 3 elements in the `$lang array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will preserve the structure of original $lang array:

```
$find = 'value1';
$result = array_filter($lang, function($rec) use ($find) {
    return in_array($find, $rec);
});
```

Where $result will be:

```
array (
  'lbl_mylabel1' => 
  array (
    'key1' => 'value1',
  ),
  'lbl_mylabel2' => 
  array (
    'key2' => 'value1',
  ),
  'lbl_mylabel3' => 
  array (
    'key3' => 'value1',
  ),
)
```

Comment: excellent , Sergiy thnx . actually more of my focus was to use a built in function rather than looping on it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean:

```
$result = array();
$value1 = 'value1';
foreach($lang['lbl_mylabel1'] as $la)
{
   if(in_array($value1)) 
   {
      $result[] = $la;
   }
}
```

Comment: the `$lang` array contains around 600  elements , so I am trying to avoid loops on it. I want to compare a values with the values of the items in the `sub-array` that is assigned to the $lang array.